# Patch-Clamping Neurons Resources

Tags: biophysics, electrophysiology

1. Are there any lectures available on Patch-Clamping?
2. Were can I find a mathematical model of Patch-Clamp? (that can be easily implemented in matlab).
3. I have found some step-by-step protocols on (Springer book site) but nothing to useful--I am setting up a new rig. Where can I find protocols that have worked and have been tested?

Comment: "The Axon guide for electrophysiology & biophysics laboratory techniques" is a very good starting point, albeit a bit biased towards Axon instrumentation. The book used to be hosted and freely downloadable on the Axon Instruments website but since they have now been acquired I cannot seem to find an official link anymore. However many other websites still host it (I won't directly link to them, as I am not sure about the licence of the book. Anyway, again, it used to be available for free).

Comment: 1. That is one of the basics of neurophysiology. You will find video lectures on youtube. 2. See GHK (Goldman-Hodgkin-Katz) model

Comment: @nico : could you perhaps convert your comment into an answer? This question may not survive. The question is quite broad, but your comment is equally broad and is quite apt. I like it!

Comment: @ChrisStronks if nico doesn't respond then we can paste the comment and post it as community wiki

Comment: @WYSIWYG I didn't know that was possible?! Interesting! (I'd like to know more about that - something for chat:-) Anyway, I would definitely prefer your suggested option above waiting for the question to be deleted, which will be anytime soon

Comment: @ChrisStronks well, the question is on hold now...